# Select first input box Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm writing a Python app that will interact with certain websites. I need to select the 1st input box in the website, how do I do this without knowing the name of said input box? I currently have

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open("http://localhost")  
br.select_form(nr=0)
# ???

br.method = "GET"
response = br.submit()
print response
```

But I'm stuck on what to do next? I've looked on various webpages but none seem to answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
inputName = br.form.find_control(nr=0).name
br.form[inputName] = value
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Is "name" a variable that I have to define?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check if [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) can help?

Comment: Selenium is a nightmare

Comment: Unfortunately, python mechanize is also a nightmare.